# Reading Large PCAP with Tshark in Smaller Parts

Tags: python, pcap, tshark

I have a PCAP file that I want to read with the `tshark` command, but it is too large to fit into memory (9GB but reading each packet fills up 35GB of Google Colab after about 30 million packets).

Therefore, I would like to split it into four parts that I can read and process separately. I have tried to split it by filtering on a frame's time using the line below. However, this continues scanning over all packets, so it takes too long.

```py
!tshark -Y "(tcp or udp) && (frame.time <= \"2019-10-21 05:00:01\")"  -r $file_name -l -T fields -e $FIELDS
```

What is the best way to process a PCAP file that is too large for memory? How can I split it without losing any packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, tshark will read and analyze all packets before doing anything else.

You should consider using *tcpdump* instead whom packet analysis is lighter.

Something like this should be (a little) faster:

> tcpdump -r "Your_file" -w "ouput_filename" -C 2250

Where 2250 is the size (in Mbytes) of each of the 4 new output files.

Comment: Poster asked to split a 9GB file into 4 parts. Perhaps change the value for `-C` to 2250 to match the question?

Comment: Yes, in that case, it should be 2250, my mistake.

Comment: Cool I'll edit it (there's an edit button at the bottom of your answer).

Comment: Thank you, tcpdump is exactly what I was looking for!